# I want to save an image from a Windows Forms application to SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm doing a Student Management project where student image must be included. But I don't know how to convert and save an image from WinForms to the database. I'll be thankful if you help me.

Here is the code I've tried to select an image. Now I need to save this image to database:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        OpenFileDialog dialog= new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Open File";
        dialog.Filter= "pngfiles(*.png)|*.png|jpgfiles(*.jpg)|*.jpg|jpegfiles(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Allfiles(*.*)|*.*";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a `byte[]`

`var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dialog.FileName);`

then set a `byte[]` property on some tracked entity.

`myEntity.ImageBytes = imageBytes;`

then save the entity to the database using `DbContext.SaveChanges()`